# Regex Split String at particular word pattern

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am trying to split a string that could look like this:

```
International Bank for Reconstruction & Development (NAICS: 928120; SIC: 6081) World Bank (NAICS: 928120; SIC: 6081)
```

into this

```
International Bank for Reconstruction & Development
World Bank
```

or any of this:

```
International Bank for Reconstruction & Development
International Bank for Reconstruction & Development (SIC: 6081)
International Bank for Reconstruction & Development (NAICS: 928120)
```

into this

```
International Bank for Reconstruction & Development
```

there could be any number of matches.

I've tried a few things, using negative characters classes doesn't work:

```
[^\(NAICS: (\d+);\)]+
```

I'm using C# Regex.

Comment: What are you trying to split it *into*? What are the results you want for each of those examples?

Comment: Each "name" into it's own match. so International Bank for Reconstruction & Development (NAICS: 928120; SIC: 6081) World Bank (NAICS: 928120; SIC: 6081) matches this set of matches { International Bank for Reconstruction & Development, World Bank}

Comment: A character class (negative or not) matches *individual characters*, not *character sequences*. This `[^\(NAICS: (\d+);\)]+` is the same as this `[^ ()+:;ACINS\d]+`

Comment: How can you tell where one name ends and the next begins? In particular, `International Bank for Reconstruction & Development World Bank` seems pretty ambiguous to me.

Comment: ruakh, I can only split if there is a (NAICS: ######) or (SIC: ######) or some combination of those in between each string, otherwise you are right, too ambiguous and it should be treated as one match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a regex to split on this might work `\([^)]*(?:(?:SIC|NAICS):[^)]*)+\)`

You could do it without split. I would take a find_all regex approach.

```
(?!\s*$)(.*?)(?:\([^)]*(?:(?:SIC|NAICS):[^)]*)+\)|$)
Modifiers: s (dot allows newline) and g (global)
```

Be warned, this will allow non '(SIC:/NAICS:)' to be allowed in the Title.
But, they aren't the delimeter right?

**edit**

My apologies. Those two regexs' can be shortened to

`\([^)]*(?:SIC|NAICS):[^)]*\)`

and

`(?!\s*$)(.*?)(?:\([^)]*(?:SIC|NAICS):[^)]*\)|$)`

Comment: The second one is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To break the string into:

```
International Bank for Reconstruction & Development
World Bank
```

you can use: http://fiddle.re/bu4a . Try  .Net!

```
^([^\(]+) \([^\)]+\) ([^\(]+) \([^\)]+\)
```

The first group will contain "**International Bank for Reconstruction & Development**", the second - "**World Bank**"